# OpenGL - how to construct an FPS style camera(the gun attached to it will move and rotate with it)

Tags: java, opengl, camera

my question is pretty directly: how to construct FPS camera, like in shooter games(you have gun, and whenever you rotate camera, gun rotates too.)

Actually, moving is no problem, just(well, before i start coding, i want to say, i am using libGDX which is an opengl framework, but you would understand to all as i would understand to opengl code) :

```
gun.transform.setTranslation(camera.position);// sets gun to the center of the camera
camera.rotate(0,1,0,-3); //rotates direction and up vector of the camera
gun.transform.rotate(0,1,0,-3); // rotates the gun
gum.transform.trn(0.18f, -0.12f, -0.24f); //offseting the gun, to be everytime in the right bottom corner of the screen
```

but this does not work. The camera is rotating kind of more than the gun. it looks like camera is sphere and.. it isnt what i want.

Comment: The position of the camera has to change with the angle of the gun.

Comment: how to calculate that? i was trying to do something like that, but it wasnt very precise

Comment: Remove the view matrix and any transforms that translate the model in relation to the players position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the trick is, not trying to move the player active item into the view, but to reset the view to identity just for drawing the player active idem model. I.e.

```
load_identity_transformation()
apply_player_camera_transformation()
draw_world()

load_identity_transformation()
apply_camera_transformation() // for perspective
draw_player_active_item()
```

You may want to apply a bobbing animation to the model when moving.

Caveat: Doing it this way breaks the experience in a Virtual Reality system (think Oculus Rift). But just using a gobal player model and applying that transformation doesn't work either. Valve has released research material on that.

Comment: Im trying to do that, and nothing is actually happening. In the start of render func i am calling: cam.view.idt();
               cam.update(); after that positing the camera, then drawing everything, expect of gun. after drawing i call the cam.view.idt();
         cam.update(); again, again positing the camera and drawing the last thing, but nothing is happening. it looks like it looked.